# How to dispatch SharePoint user to different landing page per their user group immediately after login

Tags: sharepoint, dispatcher, usergroups

I got a requirement to dispatch users to different landing page per their user group immediately after login, it seems SharePoint does not supply an API regarding login event, so I implemented a web part and added it to homepage to handle the dispatch, this would work perfect util users logout and login, SharePoint has a history where users were in their last login, to be precise, a parameter in url named `Source` to handle the redirect after login, so users will on longer go to their customized landing page.

I searched a lot and found someone doing this with custom login from, this is way too complex and client won't let me touch their Active Directory.

I'm at my wit's end to know what to do, can someone shed some light on this, any help or advise is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a delegate control in the masterpage, that checks a value in the session if you entered through the landing page. On the landing page you add the value to the session specifying that this user has entered through the landing page.

Comment: I do not know too much about sharepoint master page related stuff, any articles you can share regarding how to do this? thx!